# The translation (of the article) has been going on all day

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

Is this sentence the correct/idiomatic? If not, could you please tell me why?

"The translation (of the article) has been going on all day."

Comment: Yes the sentence is correct.  Which part of the sentence don't you understand?

Comment: If not, not if no.

Comment: What about this sentence strikes you as problematic?

Comment: Thank you. I just heard from a native that that sentence is not idiomatic at least and I should use "The translation (of the article) is taking all day." instead of that.